# retrive data from other query in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

well I'm working on a project , I'm using mysql & php to retrive my data from my table 
actually I have one table contains these fields image , name , more detail 
I made a query that will retrive all images on my table and the names , and now I'm trying to make another query and it should work like this:
first I wanna retrive my data depends on my first query and after that when I click on any image that I retrieved from the first query it should go to another query which will contains only the image that I clicked on and its name and its details , the problem that I faced is that when I click on any image I got all the images , their names and their details :

my code:

```
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS img,name FROM info LIMIT ".$start.", ".$perpage);  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

   $rows_result= mysql_query("select FOUND_ROWS() as r");
   $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($rows_result);
   $total_rows= $r['r'];
   $lastpage = ceil($total_rows / $perpage);

   echo'<div class="h" >   
        <p>  &nbsp; <a href="query2.php><img src="/'.$row['img'].'", width=100 height=100 /></a>
        <p> '.$row['name'].'</p>
   </div>';

} ?>
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store image's id (or name, anything you use as your unique key) somewhere and select by it.

For example, if you have a table with `'image_id'` being an unique id of image, you can use `WHERE` operator to get only image that you want like this:

`SELECT * FROM info WHERE image_id='1337'`

1337 is your selected image id.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point , actually I need one query that will retrive the image , its name and its details , and this query will retrive different images depends on what image I clicked on , for example , If I have 10 images on my page when I click on any image I will get this image and its details , so I can't do many queries since I have more than 100 images , I need only one query every time change and this display info of image that I clicked on , I hope you got my point

Comment: @WafaGh You can move this query to other script and call it with supplied image id using AJAX when you click the image, so your information will be retrieved only if user asks for it.

Comment: is there any way without using AJAX ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I see two ways. The first way is to load the information through iframe, and the second way is to get information about all shown images, but the page can become very heavy. Second idea relies on storing information about in invisible containers (div with display:none, for example) and getting requested information from them using JS. But it's a slightly rude solution I think.